# EJB context in javax.transaction.Synchronization.beforeCompletion versus javax.ejb.BeforeCompletion

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jta, apache-tomee, openejb

In TomEE when a ejb is registering a Synchronization in the transaction synchronization registry, there is no ejb context in beforeCompletion. When using bean javax.ejb.BeforeCompletion there is. What should be expected according to the jee/ejb specs?

See below code test case testWithWrappedUserTransaction is failing:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.AfterBegin;
import javax.ejb.AfterCompletion;
import javax.ejb.BeforeCompletion;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.EJBException;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.transaction.Synchronization;
import javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import org.apache.openejb.core.ThreadContext;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TransactionTest extends TestCase
{
@Resource
private TransactionSynchronizationRegistry  registry;

@Resource
private UserTransaction transaction;
@EJB
private Caller transactionalCaller;

@EJB
private Caller transactionalCaller2;

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    final Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("movieDatabase", "new://Resource?type=DataSource");
    p.put("movieDatabase.JdbcDriver", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    p.put("movieDatabase.JdbcUrl", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:moviedb");

    EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p).getContext().bind("inject", this);
}

private void doWork() throws Exception {
    registry.registerInterposedSynchronization(new SynchronizationImplementation());
}

class SynchronizationImplementation implements Synchronization
{
    @Override
    public void beforeCompletion() {
        System.out.println("XXX: beforeCommit");
        assertEJBContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(int paramInt) {
        System.out.println("XXX: afterCommit");
        assertEJBContext();
    }
}

private static void assertEJBContext() {
    assertTrue(ThreadContext.getThreadContext() != null);
}

public void testWithWrappedUserTransaction() throws Exception {
    transaction.begin();
    try {
        transactionalCaller.call(() -> {
            doWork();
            return null;
        });
    } finally {
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

public void testWithDoubleBeanTransaction() throws Exception {
    transactionalCaller.call(() -> {
        doWork2();
        return null;
    });
}

private void doWork2() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("XXX: doWork2");
    transactionalCaller2.call(() -> {
        doWork();
        return null;
    });
}

public void testWithTransaction() throws Exception {
    transactionalCaller.call(() -> {
        doWork();
        return null;
    });
}

public static interface Caller
{
    public <V> V call(Callable<V> callable) throws Exception;
}
```

}

ps: I logged ticket for TomEE but got no response: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-2135

Answer (score 1):

You cant assume it exists since the hooks are executed after ejb invocation so potentially outside an EJBContext and using the UT it is under your responsability, not EJB container one.

Comment: What if I start a transaction in web context A and then call a bean in web context B? I expect the transaction hooks of B are executed in web context A, right? Is there a way to execute the transaction hooks again in/with web context B?

Comment: Transaction is bound to the thread but the JNDI context is the contextual one. Your commit being outside an EJB you don't have any EJB context.